# Regular Expression in MVC4

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have a regular expression that allows only letters, numbers and special characters but does not allow numbers, special characters and white space only. I am using this expression below but it is not working. How can I fix Iit?

```
"^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{4,10}$"
```

For example::

> Abc!@#111  - Accept
>   qwerty            - Accept
>   111             - dont accept
>   @#$          - dont accept

Comment: Now what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, letters and digits are both required. Thus, it won't match `qwerty`.

It seems you just want to make sure there is at least one letter.

If you plan to use server-side validation only, you can use a .NET regex that allows Unicode letter class `\P{L}` meaning *non-letter*:

```
^(?!\P{L}*$)\S{4,10}$
```

It can be declared as `@"^(?!\P{L}*$).{4,10}$"`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!%5cP%7bL%7d*%24).%7b4%2c10%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=Abc!%40%23111%0d%0aqwerty%0d%0a+++++++++++++-+dont+accept%0d%0a111%0d%0a%40%23%24%0d%0a%40%23%241&o=m)

If you need to validate strings on the client side or both client and server side, you will need a JS compatible version (but it won't support Unicode):

```
^(?![^A-Za-z]*$)\S{4,10}$
```

To check if *not only numbres or Special characters* are present, we can use a look-ahead `(?!\P{L}*$)` that requires the use of at least one letter.

Comment: Please let me know if my current suggestion works for you. If not, please provide more sample input and expected output.

Comment: How are you using it? Please post the code. Have a look at the [sample code](http://ideone.com/jGDYSq).

Comment: in C# numbers are also accepting... but in demo its correct... am using MVC4 and framework 4.5

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"^(?!\P{L}*$).{4,10}$", ErrorMessage = "invalid Pattern")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

Comment: Try the last regex `^(?![^A-Za-z]*$).{4,10}$`. Perhaps, you are validating on both server and client side.

Comment: public class MyModel
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            [RegularExpression(@"^(?!\P{L}*$).{4,10}$", ErrorMessage = "invalid Pattern")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

Comment: The code looks OK, I think the reason is that server-side validation allows `\p{L}` and the client-side one does not.

Comment: @ stribizhev, This code is working (^(?![^A-Za-z]*$).{4,10}$) thank you. and how can i remove white space from this expression ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow only the input that DOES NOT contain spaces? Use `@"^(?![^A-Za-z]*$)\S{4,10}$"`. `\S` matches a character that is not whitespace.